# How to convert array data to new data

Tags: javascript

I have an `initalArray` that looks like this:

initailArray: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Say I want to convert `a -> apple`, `b -> berry` `c -> cat` and `d -> dog`

so my newArray should look like this:

```
newArray: ["apple", "berry", "cat", "dog"]
```

Is there a way I could do this? I think I need to use `if` or `switch`. But 
don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `map` to go over the `initialArray`, like this:

```
let initialArray =  ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

let newArray = initialArray.map(item => {
  switch(item) {
    case 'a':
      return 'apple';
      break;
    case 'b':
      return 'berry'
      break;
    case 'c':
      return 'cat';
      break;
    case 'd':
      return 'dog';
      break;
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could just use an object as a map that contains each letter and their corresponding values.
2. Then you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and for each letter return the respective value from the map.

```js
/* @type {{[letter: string]: string}} Map of letters and corresponding values */
var alphabetMap = {
  "a": "apple",
  "b": "berry",
  "c": "cat",
  "d": "dog",
};


var initialArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

// transform array of letters to array of respective values
console.log(initialArray.map(function(letter) {
  // for each letter return value of `alphabetMap` for that letter
  return alphabetMap[letter] || "Invalid Letter"; // Nice to have a default value
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` to convert each item to the item from a given mapping.

```js
const mapping = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'berry',
  c: 'cat',
  d: 'dog'
};
const initialArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

const result = initialArray.map(entry => mapping[entry]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have a "map" from codes ("a", "b" ecc...) and your values ("apple", "berry" ...):

```
let myMap = { a: "apple", b: "berry", c: "cat", d:"dog" };
```

Then you can use the "map" method of Array:

```
let newArray = initialArray.map((key) => myMap[key]);
```

```js
let initialArray = ["a","b","c","d"];
let myMap = { a: "apple", b: "berry", c: "cat", d:"dog" };
let newArray = initialArray.map((key) => myMap[key]);
document.write(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mapping = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'berry',
  c: 'cat',
  d: 'dog'
};
const result = ["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(ele=>mapping[ele]);


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
for (i = 0; i < initailArray.length; i++){
 if(initailArray[i] == "a"){
initailArray[i] == "apple"
}
else if (initailArray[i] == "b"){
initailArray[i] == "berry"
}
else if (initailArray[i] == "c"){
initailArray[i] == "cat"
}
else if (initailArray[i] == "d"){
initailArray[i] == "dog"
}

}
```